# ImportError while trying to import matplotlib and nltk in VS code on my MacBook Pro M1

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-import, importerror

I'm encountering an error while trying to import matplotlib using:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The error message reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/j0/ftm7j2sn2wv9wj4rhq038q7h0000gn/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.11 from "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.24.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

I am using a MacBook with an M1 chip, and it seems that there might be an issue with the architecture. Can anyone suggest a solution to resolve this issue?

I tried updating pip, and reinstalling numpy and matplotlib. It is working perfectly in PyCharm after I tried some fixes on the internet. But, VS code is still throwing error.

Comment: so... what did you find when trying to use the troubleshooting steps that were linked to in the error message? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11107541. One key part of your error message: "_, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))_"

Comment: Reinstall the nuhh and myald packages (compatible with your machine's M1 chip) for your environment. `pip3 install numpy matplotlib` or `pip3 install numpy -f https://numpy.org/downloads/macosx/
pip3 install matplotlib -f https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/installing.html#installation-for-macos`.